# empty fields in a class

Tags: django, field

For a target field, I would like to create a function in a class. That function will empty all fields, except the target field, whenever the field `income_source` is different of `Employed`. How could I ask to empty each field in my class?

Thanks in advance!

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class EmployerProfile(AbstractAddress):
    income_source = models.CharField(_('Income source'), max_length=20,
                                 choices=settings.LOANWOLF_INCOME_SOURCE_CHOICES,
                                 default='employed')


    company_name = models.CharField(_('Company name'),
                                    max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = PhoneField(_('Phone'), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_extension = models.CharField(_('Extension'), max_length=10,
                                       blank=True, null=True)
    job_title = models.CharField(_('Job title'), max_length=50, blank=True,
                                 null=True)
    date_hired = models.DateField(_('Date hired'), blank=True, null=True)
    supervisor_name = models.CharField(_('Supervisor name'), max_length=50,
                                       blank=True, null=True)
    has_missing_fields = models.BooleanField(_('Has missing informations'),
                                             default=True)
    manual_validation = GenericRelation(ManualFieldValidation)
```

Comment: Please show the class

Comment: @Julien It's done! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to clear these depending on the field, it's best to do this before the model instance is saved. Additionally, we don't want to clear *all* the fields, it's better to be explicit about which ones we want to clear.

This is untested, but let me know how this works out for you:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.company_name != "employed":
        to_empty = [ 
            "company_name",
            "phone",
            "phone_extension",
            "job_title",
            "date_hired",
            "supervisor_name",
        ]
        for field_name in to_empty:
            setattr(self, field_name, None)
    super(EmployerProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you're using Python 3, then the last line is just:

```
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, I'd appreciate an upvote too if you found this useful :)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't upvote. My score is too low for the moment

Comment: If you are familiar with metaclasses, could you tell me if it is possible to simplify the function with a metaclass?